# Problem with remote Button method post to redirect in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My problem: When place is not present controller does not redirect to the route i want.

I have a link_to , check_payer post route

```
<%= link_to "Click here", check_path, method: :post, remote: true %>
```

this methods verify if place is present and if true is not redirecting to other_path

Comment: I don't understand, you say the problem is that **When place is not present controller does not redirect to the route i want**, the controller has a redirect when place IS present, and when it's NOT present you are rendering a js view that opens a modal. do you want it to show a modal or redirect?

Comment: I need both, when is present i want to redirect to that path, when it's not open modal, is it possible?

Comment: What I mean is that you are describing the opposite of what you show in the code, in the code you are trying to redirect if the place IS PRESENT, but you say you want to redirect when the place IS NOT PRESENT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of `remote: true` the request will come in as `xhr` and render `check_payer.js.erb`. This `.js.erb` contains something that the browser knows how to interpret/execute.

In your scenario when the redirect happens, the browser doesn't know what to do with the response. If you open the browser console (or Inspector) in `Network` tab you will see it makes a redirect to `billings_path`.

To handle both scenarios you need to handle everything inside `check_payer.js.erb`.

```
# check_payer.js.erb

<% if @place.present? %>
  window.location = "<%= billings_path %>"
<% else %>
  $('#modal-check-payer').find(".modal-content").html("<%= j render partial:'place_billing_infos/check_payer_modal' %>");
  $("#modal-check-payer").modal();
<% end %>
```